# How to trim the elements before assigning it into an array list?

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I need to assign the elements present in a CSV file into an arraylist. CSV file contains filenames with extension .tar. I need to trim those elements before i read it into an array list or trim the whole arraylist. Please help me with it

```
try
   {
    String strFile1 = "D:\\Ramakanth\\PT2573\\target.csv";  //csv file containing data
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(strFile1)); //create BufferedReader 
    String strLine1 = "";
    StringTokenizer st1 = null;

    while( (strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null) //read comma separated file line by line
    {
     st1 = new StringTokenizer(strLine1, ","); //break comma separated line using ","

     while(st1.hasMoreTokens())
     {
      array1.add(st1.nextToken()); //store csv values in array
     }
    }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println("Exception while reading csv file: " + e);                  
   }
```

Comment: Do you mean skip those elements (not add them to the list)? Then a simple `if` statement would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the ".tar" string from your tokens, you can use:

```
String nextToken = st1.nextToken();
if (nextToken.endsWith(".tar")) {
    nextToken = nextToken.replace(".tar", "");
}
array1.add(nextToken);
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing parenthesis after `endsWith(".tar")`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) the JavaDoc says (in part) *`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.* You should close your `BufferedReader`. You could use a [`try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to do that. And, you might use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate the array produced by [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the regular expression below optionally matches whitespace before or after your `,` and you might `continue` the loop if the `token` endsWith ".tar" like

```
String strFile1 = "D:\\Ramakanth\\PT2573\\target.csv"; 
try (BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strFile1)))
{
  String strLine1 = "";
  while( (strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = strLine1.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    for (String token : parts) {
      if (token.endsWith(".tar")) continue; // <-- don't add "tar" files.
      array1.add(token);
    }
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("Exception while reading csv file: " + e);                  
}
```

Comment: All good advice, but does not address the question about trimming the tar files (whatever that means exactly).

Comment: (unless it does mean "trim whitespace around the file names", which it could...)

Comment: @Thilo Edited to skip tar files.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(st1.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String input = st1.nextToken();
    int index = input.indexOf(".");  // Get the position of '.'

    if(index >= 0){     // To avoid StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, when there is no match with '.' then the index position set to -1.
        array1.add(input.substring(0, index)); // Get the String before '.' position.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str.indexOf(".tar") >0)
str = str.subString(0, str.indexOf(".tar")-1);
```